# Material Ui - Unable to enter input textfield/ set values on a controlled component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to create a custom input component with inputRef (material ui Input component). Looks like the component reference is working but I'm unable to enter any value in the text field after i set the **value attribute**. I think it's because of the way i implemented the onchange event. I'm not sure what am i missing. Please help.

Here is the codesandbox url

https://codesandbox.io/s/pjlwqvwrvm

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need a onChange prop to for get the changed value..

Just get the value from onchange and set the value in state `value`.

Another mistake is you are not created the constructor, and gave this.props.value to the value prop. That's it not get updated..

Now I created the constructor and give the this.state.value to the value props.

Now you get your onchanged value in custominput component and your submit function also..

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Input } from "material-ui-next";
import trimStart from "lodash/trimStart";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const defaultProps = {
  state: "",
  onChange: () => {} // no need
};

const propTypes = {
  state: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value:''
    }
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("state: " + this.state.value); //shows onChanged value in console
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <CustomInput
            labelText="State"
            id="state"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={e=> {
              this.setState({value:e.target.value})
            }}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = propTypes;
App.defaultProps = defaultProps;

class CustomInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      formControlProps,
      value,
      onChange,
      labelText,
      id,
      labelProps,
      inputRef,
      inputProps
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div {...formControlProps}>
        {labelText !== undefined ? (
          <div htmlFor={id} {...labelProps}>
            {labelText}
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <Input
          classes={{
            root: labelText !== undefined ? "" : classes.marginTop
          }}
          id={id}
          value={value} ///////// Fixed ////////
          onChange={onChange}
          inputRef={inputRef}
          {...inputProps}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is code in sandbox check it..

https://codesandbox.io/s/84rjk4m8l8

Answer (score 3):

1. You can either go on inputRef - then your value and onChange event are extra - it is called uncontrolled Component. You can see more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html
2. Or you can do it with value & onChange event - and work with controlled components, you can find more about controlled components here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

How to solve it (uncontrollable) with inputRef:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("input value: ", this.input.value); // will now show you correct input value
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <CustomInput
            labelText="State"
            id="state"
            inputRef={input => {
              this.input = input;
            }}
          />
          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} color='primary'>Submit</Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of "this.state = input", bind input to something else, because this.state is reserved for local state of React Component, and it won't work with it, not like that.

How to solve it (controllable) with state, value & onChange event:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: props.state || ''
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("state: ", this.state.value); // will now show you correct input value
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const {value} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <CustomInput
            labelText="State"
            id="state"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={value}
          />
          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} color='primary'>Submit</Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I added the constructor and defined the local state for component, and I'm changing value inside of state with this.setState (because state is immutable, and that's the right way to update it).

In both examples, you are able to get input value inside of handleSubmit method, will you work with controllable or uncontrollable components, it's up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `value={this.state}` or `value={this.value}`

Here is Your sandbox code Updated

https://codesandbox.io/s/qqk2qoxmlj

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was mistakenly using state from parent component in child component, since I had declared child component inside parent itself. Moving whole state to child component solved the problem.